# I want to fetch column values from column name rollnoofstud of tableA using PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
 TYPE norollno IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
      rollno norollno;
BEGIN
   BEGIN
      SELECT token
      BULK COLLECT INTO rollno
      FROM tableA
      WHERE columname='rollnoofstud';
   EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      rollno := norollno();
  END ;

  IF rollno >0 THEN
  FOR i IN rollno.FIRST..norollno.LAST
  LOOP
    <doSomeThing>
  END LOOP;
  END IF;
END;
```

I am trying this but I am not getting output. I doubt if my select statement is correct.

Comment: Why is this tagged _bash_?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have your table so I created one:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE tablea
  2  AS
  3     SELECT ename AS token, 'rollnoofstud' AS columname
  4       FROM emp
  5      WHERE deptno = 10;

Table created.
```

Code you posted isn't that wrong; requires a little bit of fixing (see line #17, the way you check whether collection contains something (*count* it!); typo in FOR loop):

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2     TYPE norollno IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (100);
  3
  4     rollno  norollno;
  5  BEGIN
  6     BEGIN
  7        SELECT token
  8          BULK COLLECT INTO rollno
  9          FROM tableA
 10         WHERE columname = 'rollnoofstud';
 11     EXCEPTION
 12        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
 13        THEN
 14           rollno := norollno ();
 15     END;
 16
 17     IF rollno.COUNT > 0
 18     THEN
 19        FOR i IN rollno.FIRST .. rollno.LAST
 20        LOOP
 21           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (rollno (i));
 22        END LOOP;
 23     END IF;
 24  END;
 25  /
CLARK                    --> here's the result
KING
MILLER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT: with your sample table and data:]**

(note that there's no `text` datatype in Oracle!)

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE students
  2  (
  3     rollnostud   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  4     name         VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL,
  5     gender       VARCHAR2 (1) NOT NULL
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO students
  2       VALUES (1, 'Ryan', 'M');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO students
  2       VALUES (2, 'Joanna', 'F');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO students
  2       VALUES (3, 'John', 'M');

1 row created.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2     TYPE norollno IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (100);
  3
  4     rollno  norollno;
  5  BEGIN
  6     BEGIN
  7        SELECT name
  8          BULK COLLECT INTO rollno
  9          FROM students;
 10     EXCEPTION
 11        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
 12        THEN
 13           rollno := norollno ();
 14     END;
 15
 16     IF rollno.COUNT > 0
 17     THEN
 18        FOR i IN rollno.FIRST .. rollno.LAST
 19        LOOP
 20           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (rollno (i));
 21        END LOOP;
 22     END IF;
 23  END;
 24  /
Ryan
Joanna
John

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I am getting this error "COLUMNAME": invalid identifier

Comment: I just have the table in SQL. I have not declared anything as token or columnname like you have done. I just have 3  columns and 3 rows in my table

Comment: You **must** be kidding! Check code you posted - it contains COLUMNAME and TOKEN so I posted code which uses columns **you used**. If you can't adjust it to your real table and its column names, then I'm afraid I can't help much either.

Comment: but why  am I getting this error?

Comment: Because your table doesn't contain column named COLUMNAME.

Comment: I have a column named rollnostud . And I need to retrieve the values in this column

Comment: It would actually help if you post table description and some sample data we could work with, because what you *say* is different from code you posted and it is difficult to provide something useful as - apparently - you can't find the way out of your problems.

Comment: CREATE TABLE students (
  rollnostud INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  gender TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO students VALUES (1, 'Ryan', 'M');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (2, 'Joanna', 'F');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (3, 'John', 'M');

Comment: Have a look at edited answer, please.